Local Server Only Accessible Through Localhost Even After Portforwarding
On my Windows computer, I'm running a server out of a folder through NodeJS. It's a Pokemon Showdown server that is created just by downloading a ZIP of their Git repo, installing NodeJS and NPM, and running a file that creates a web server, accessible either by going to localhost:8000 or by going to server-ipv4:8000. It can be accessed through localhost just fine. However, when trying to use the IP, even locally from a browser on the same machine that runs the server, it gives this error:

I've read up that this happens due to a mismatched or invalid SSL certificate, but the personal servers that Pokemon Showdown allows you to make are accessed through HTTP and their link is an IP address, so I can't get an SSL certificate for these servers. If anybody has any idea of why this might be happening or how to help, anything is appreciated!
